# How to render a texture of an object from it's color, uvs and lighting?

Tags: texture, maya

I have a rock in my project:

[image]

And it's UV's:
[image]

It has a standard `Arnold` material: `Ai Standard Surface` with a grey color.
There's also some lighting on the scene.

I'm trying to generate a texture which will combine the grey color, the UVs and the lighting so it will output something like this:

*Please ignore white lines in the image, I colored it in Photoshop

[image]

This is because I want to use this texture later in Unity as Unlit so it will look exactly the same in Unity, as it looked on a Maya Render.

I've already tried `TransferMaps` but it doesn't seem to work and it outputs a completely grey texture (which is even darker than the color in the shader).

Is something like this possible to achieve?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a way to BAKE the lighting and/or texture. Don’t know how to do that in Maya, but searching “maya bake lighting” seems to throw up a few potential solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Maya since about version 5, having moved over to modo years ago for most of my heavy 3D work, but I am 100% certain you can bake textures there without trouble.

I can tell you how I'd do that in modo, and hopefully there's enough which is at least concept transferrable that it will give you a direction to investigate in Maya's documentation - though to be honest I strongly suspect this is both so basic and so common a need that there are hundreds of tutorials out there on this.

In modo one can create a new empty image file and target it in the renderer, setting it as a bake target, and you can tell modo to bake all current visible render items and output to that file - this will give you local colour, direct illumination / shading and indirect / global illumination and occlusion all in one map - the render engine then fires up, does a render to that file, and then saves - you now have a single texture file which captures all that info - when you export out your FBX to Unity, you should get a perfect texture map for an unlit shader to look exactly as you expect.

You might also consider asking this in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/117017/ as there will be a ton of Maya-to-Unity workflow folks there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey. Turned out that Standard Maya can't do that. Arnold renderer can do that, but you can't customize it and you get artifacts because you can't make the output texture bleed so you get seams. The best results so far I had with TURTLE renderer and Redshift. But it works like a charm and it's called "Baking to the Texture". Thanks for the help!